# Converting javascript filter() and forEach() shorthand to Python

Tags: python

I'm converting some code from Javascript to Python. As I'm not an experienced coder, know only a bit from Javascript and next to nothing from Python it's a challenge. I'm getting there but I'm stuck on this piece of code. It filters an array and updates the entries found with a new value.

```
array.filter(entry => entry.field_to_match === value_to_match).forEach(entry => entry.field_to_match = new_value);
```

Is there a Python guru out there that can rewrite this in Python?

What I have so far is that I can get the entries that match the filter. But O'm not sure how to update the array in that loop. Here is what I have.

```
for key in array:
    if (key['field_to_match'] == value_to_match):
        print(key)
```

The actual array looks like this:

```
[{'port_idx': 1, 'portconf_id': '5f342xxxxcc6e1', 'port_security_mac_address': [], 'name': 'Edgerouter X'}, {'port_idx': 2, 'portconf_id': '5f342bxxxxcc6e1', 'port_security_mac_address': [], 'name': 'Diskstation'}, {'port_idx': 3, 'portconf_id': '5f3xxxxxxc6e1', 'port_security_mac_address': [], 'name': 'Diskstation2'}, {'port_idx': 4, 'portconf_id': '5fxxxx6e1', 'port_security_mac_address': [], 'name': 'Omvormer'}, {'port_idx': 5, 'portconf_id': '5f342xxxxxxcc6e1', 'poe_mode': 'auto', 'port_security_mac_address': [], 'name': 'Woonkamer'}, {'port_idx': 6, 'portconf_id': '5f34xxxxxcc6e1', 'poe_mode': 'auto', 'port_security_mac_address': [], 'name': '1e verdieping'}, {'port_idx': 7, 'portconf_id': '5f342xxxxcc6e1', 'poe_mode': 'off', 'port_security_mac_address': [], 'name': 'Slaapkamer'}, {'port_idx': 8, 'portconf_id': '5f342bxxxxc6e1', 'poe_mode': 'auto', 'port_security_mac_address': [], 'name': 'DoorBird'}]
```

and I want the end result to look like this (where poe_mode has been updated to off for port with port_idx 6)

```
[{'port_idx': 1, 'portconf_id': '5f342xxxxcc6e1', 'port_security_mac_address': [], 'name': 'Edgerouter X'}, {'port_idx': 2, 'portconf_id': '5f342bxxxxcc6e1', 'port_security_mac_address': [], 'name': 'Diskstation'}, {'port_idx': 3, 'portconf_id': '5f3xxxxxxc6e1', 'port_security_mac_address': [], 'name': 'Diskstation2'}, {'port_idx': 4, 'portconf_id': '5fxxxx6e1', 'port_security_mac_address': [], 'name': 'Omvormer'}, {'port_idx': 5, 'portconf_id': '5f342xxxxxxcc6e1', 'poe_mode': 'auto', 'port_security_mac_address': [], 'name': 'Woonkamer'}, {'port_idx': 6, 'portconf_id': '5f34xxxxxcc6e1', 'poe_mode': 'off', 'port_security_mac_address': [], 'name': '1e verdieping'}, {'port_idx': 7, 'portconf_id': '5f342xxxxcc6e1', 'poe_mode': 'off', 'port_security_mac_address': [], 'name': 'Slaapkamer'}, {'port_idx': 8, 'portconf_id': '5f342bxxxxc6e1', 'poe_mode': 'auto', 'port_security_mac_address': [], 'name': 'DoorBird'}]
```

Comment: What have you tried? Did you try to dissect this one line into its parts, so you can translate it piece by piece?

Comment: I have updated the post, I can loop through the array and get the elements I'm looking for but I dont know how to update the whole array for these items with the new value.

Comment: Can you show what `array` look like in you question? and the final output you want.

Comment: I have updated the initial post with the current and desired `array`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`result = array.filter(predicate_function)` can be translated to a generator comprehension: `result = (value for value in array if predicate_function(value))`, which is lazily evaluated.

`result = array.forEach(function)` can be translated to `result = map(function, array)`, which results in another lazily evaluated generator.

To compute the values, a constructor like `list` or `tuple` is needed.

So what you likely want is something like this:

```
list(map(lambda value: setattr(value, field_to_match, new_value), (value for value is array if array.field_to_match == value_to_match)))
```

This one-liner also preserves all the ugliness of JavaScript.

A more pythonic solution would be:

```
for value in array:
    if value.field_to_match == value_to_match:
        value.field_to_match = new_value
```

Comment: The more pythonic solution does not update the original array with new values. There is so much in the one-liner that I'm still trying to understand what is going on there.

Comment: It updates the object `value`, which is still stored in the original array. The one-liner is stupidly overengineered, don't use it.

Comment: You are right, works. Thanx.